# Unit testing for EditTextView. How do I do it?

Tags: android, junit

```
public class LoginActivityTest extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2<Login> {


        Login mActivity;
        private EditText username;
        private EditText password;

          @SuppressWarnings("deprecation")
        public LoginActivityTest()
          {
              super("com.main.account.Login",Login.class);
          }


          @Override
        protected void setUp() throws Exception {
              super.setUp();
              mActivity = this.getActivity();

              username = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.username);
              password = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.password);
                      }

          public void testPreconditions() { 
              assertNotNull(username);
              assertNotNull(password);
            }


          public void testText() {
              assertEquals("hello",username.getText());
              assertEquals("hello123", password.getText());
            }

}
```

Error I get is this:

```
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376): junit.framework.AssertionFailedError: expected:<hello> but was:<>
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.Assert.fail(Assert.java:47)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.Assert.failNotEquals(Assert.java:282)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:64)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.Assert.assertEquals(Assert.java:71)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at com.crumbs.main.test.LoginActivityTest.testText(LoginActivityTest.java:46)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invokeNative(Native Method)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at java.lang.reflect.Method.invoke(Method.java:507)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runMethod(InstrumentationTestCase.java:204)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestCase.runTest(InstrumentationTestCase.java:194)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at android.test.ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.runTest(ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2.java:186)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.TestCase.runBare(TestCase.java:127)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.TestResult$1.protect(TestResult.java:106)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.TestResult.runProtected(TestResult.java:124)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.TestResult.run(TestResult.java:109)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at junit.framework.TestCase.run(TestCase.java:118)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:169)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at android.test.AndroidTestRunner.runTest(AndroidTestRunner.java:154)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at android.test.InstrumentationTestRunner.onStart(InstrumentationTestRunner.java:529)
04-18 16:03:47.132: I/TestRunner(12376):    at android.app.Instrumentation$InstrumentationThread.run(Instrumentation.java:1448)
```

How do I test it then? As in, how do I set the values for the EditText so that I can test it here?

The documentation is a bit scattered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

it is working just fine.. Its just saying your test case failed because the text in the EditText is not equal to text your comparing to..
try this/..

```
     @Override
            protected void setUp() throws Exception {
                  super.setUp();
                  mActivity = this.getActivity();

                  username = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.username);
                  password = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.password);


                          }

              public void testPreconditions() { 
                  assertNotNull(username);
                  assertNotNull(password);
                }


              public void testText() {
//now that it will pass the test case without Exception..
//but if you want to compare text then you may have to set it in xml and then compare it.. doing it in onCreate() of Login may also work.. 
                  assertEquals("",username.getText());
                  assertEquals("", password.getText());
                }
```

Comment: I get this error: 04-18 16:35:26.632: I/TestRunner(13709): android.view.ViewRoot$CalledFromWrongThreadException: Only the original thread that created a view hierarchy can touch its views.

Comment: @Hiccup .. what is that you want to test exactly..?

Comment: A test procedure that should fail for certain usernames and pass for certain user-names. Or is this not the right way to go about it?

Comment: @Hiccup.. definetly not the right thing to do.. you need to have a method or class in your Actvity which determines whether the name is valid or not.. if invalid it should return false... now call that method in test case and pass valid and invalid values to check if the method works fine.. there is a way to check if its true or false too in unit tests..

Comment: put ur code in mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {

   public void run() { }  });

Answer (score 6):

> How do I test it then? As in, how do I set the values for the EditText so that I can test it here?

It doesn't make much sense to dummy test  EditText.setText() method, however, if you insist, do something like this:

```
public void testText() {
  // simulate user action to input some value into EditText:
  final EditText mUsername = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.username);
  final EditText mPassword = (EditText) mActivity.findViewById(R.id.password);
  mActivity.runOnUiThread(new Runnable() {
    public void run() {
      mUsername.setText("hello");
      mPassword.setText("hello123");
    }
  });

  // Check if the EditText is properly set:
  assertEquals("hello", mUsername.getText());
  assertEquals("hello123", mPassword.getText());
}
```

Hope this helps.

Answer (score 1):

This technique has the nice bonus of being able to see the test string being typed while the test is running.

This method will write a string into the editText element, where password is your test string. It should be added to the instrumentation test class (which extends ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2)

```
private void addPassword(final String password) {
    final EditText pw = (EditText) activity.findViewById(R.id.someId);
    // Send string input value
    getInstrumentation().runOnMainSync(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            pw.requestFocus();
        }
    });
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
    getInstrumentation().sendStringSync(password);
    getInstrumentation().waitForIdleSync();
}
```

You can then retrieve the text with

```
    EditText pw = (EditText)findViewById(R.id.someId);
    final String entry = pw.getText().toString().trim();
```

And compare them for equality with

```
    assertEquals(TEST_STRING, entry);
```

Hope this helps. Further information here http://developer.android.com/training/activity-testing/activity-functional-testing.html

Answer (score 0):

You can use the same methodology as the `TouchUtils`. Here is what I did:

Create a `TextUtil` class with static method so its easy to use it

```
package org.dashee.venus;

import android.app.Activity;
import android.widget.TextView;

/**
 * Provide a Text utility where a view text can be changed
 * by running inside a thread
 */
public class TextUtils
{
    public static void setText(Activity activity, final TextView view, final String text)
    {
        activity.runOnUiThread(
                new Runnable()
                {
                    @Override
                    public void run ()
                    {
                        view.setText(text);
                    }
                }
        );
    }
}
```

Then you can call It inside your testMethod

```
public void testText()
{
    TextView email = this.getActivity().findViewById(R.id.email);
    TextUtil.setText(this.getActivity(), email, "example@hello.com");
    assertEquals("example@hello.com", email.getText());
}
```

Hope this helps

Answer (score 0):

I know this is a very old post, what about this solution:

```
 @Before
public void init() {
    MockitoAnnotations.initMocks(this);

    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_logout)).thenReturn(buttonLogout);
    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.button_unlock)).thenReturn(buttonUnlock);
    when(rootView.findViewById(R.id.ScreenLock_PasswordTextField)).thenReturn(passwordField);

    when(passwordField.getText()).thenReturn(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("asd"));
    when(application.getPassword()).thenReturn("asd");

    sut = new ScreenLockPresenterImpl(application, rootView, screenLockListener,
            logoutButtonClickListener);
}


@Test
public void testOnClickWhenOk() {
    sut.onClick(null);

    verify(passwordField).getText();
    verify(screenLockListener).unLock();
}
```

I think this is what you are looking for:
**when(passwordField.getText()).thenReturn(Editable.Factory.getInstance().newEditable("asd"));**

Comment: Editable is part of Android platform code too though. In the android.text package. So it would need to be mocked too if you want to test through JUnit.